# Finding the cause of a Chromium stack trace triggered via a headless run of jasmine in linux

Tags: javascript, linux, unit-testing, jasmine, chromium

I have code that is performing javascript unit tests on known working code.  The unit tests pass on Mac and older versions of Chromium on Linux.  However on linux platforms as soon as we upgrade to the latest version of chromium we end up with a stack trace from Chromium.

- Chromium version <= 71.0.3578.80-1~deb9u1 amd64 (and below) -> works without error.
- Chromium version >= 72.0.3626.96-1~deb9u1 amd64 -> Yields the provided stack trace.

Stack Trace:

```
28 02 2019 15:31:17.564:INFO [compiler.karma-typescript]: Compiled 369 files in 6159 ms.
28 02 2019 15:31:20.117:INFO [bundler.karma-typescript]: Bundled imports for 248 file(s) in 2050 ms.
28 02 2019 15:31:20.163:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.7.1 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
28 02 2019 15:31:20.163:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser ChromeDebugging with unlimited concurrency
28 02 2019 15:31:20.167:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser ChromeHeadless
28 02 2019 15:31:20.345:ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start ChromeHeadless
    Received signal 11 SEGV_MAPERR 000000000080
#0 0x5594c1afb791 <unknown>
#1 0x5594c1afbbfb <unknown>
#2 0x5594c1afc25e <unknown>
#3 0x7f43124e80e0 <unknown>
#4 0x5594bfee3314 <unknown>
#5 0x5594bfeee1b7 <unknown>
#6 0x5594c55d65e6 <unknown>
#7 0x5594c55d669a <unknown>
#8 0x5594bfe7ffd3 <unknown>
#9 0x5594c02f9c32 <unknown>
#10 0x5594bfe82089 <unknown>
#11 0x5594bfe83039 <unknown>
#12 0x5594c60a88b5 <unknown>
#13 0x5594c15a62d7 <unknown>
#14 0x5594c15a6581 <unknown>
#15 0x5594c15a6930 <unknown>
#16 0x5594c15b1bfa <unknown>
#17 0x5594c15a4745 <unknown>
#18 0x5594c55dc363 <unknown>
#19 0x5594c55dc554 <unknown>
#20 0x5594c15aedc9 <unknown>
#21 0x5594bf24cd6d ChromeMain
#22 0x7f43049122e1 __libc_start_main
#23 0x5594bf24cb8a _start
  r8: 0000000000000001  r9: 0000000000000020 r10: 00007f42d1ffb9d0 r11: 0000000000000202
 r12: 00007fff34d242b0 r13: 00005594c976ac90 r14: 00007fff34d24300 r15: 00005594c9763230
  di: 00007fff34d242b0  si: 00005594c66938f0  bp: 00007fff34d24350  bx: 00005594c9769470
  dx: 00005594bfee3314  ax: 00007fff34d242b0  cx: 0000000000000319  sp: 00007fff34d24250
  ip: 00005594bfee3314 efl: 0000000000010206 cgf: 0000000000000033 erf: 0000000000000004
 trp: 000000000000000e msk: 0000000000000000 cr2: 0000000000000080
[end of stack trace]
Calling _exit(1). Core file will not be generated.
```

I'm looking for resources to determine the source of the problem. I have tested on Debian 9.0, Ubuntu 14.04, and Ubuntu 18.04 with the same results. These are running inside docker containers so a GUI is not readily available. I don't expect you (the reader) to solve my problem, I'm looking for resources, tools, tips, etc that can help me and my team find those problems. (Although if you can solve it kudo's to you I'd love to hear it.)

Comment: Try to update Chromium. I've had a Chromium update a couple of days ago (72.0.3626.96-1~deb9u2) and suddenly this error appeared. Updating today (72.0.3626.122-1~deb9u1) and the error is gone.